# Shell script not not running in gilab ci same way as locally

Tags: shell, docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a shell script for pulling, retagging, building and pushing my docker images and it works great when I run it locally. But when CI runs it I get an error `:ash :stable uknown operand`. I think it has to do something with different distributive of Linux used by my gilab runner. I am running on Ubuntu 18.04. And I am not sure what linux is on CI, I created as a docker gitlab runner. Here is my script:

```
docker pull $BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH:latest &> /dev/null

if [[ -n `docker images | grep "$BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH\b" | grep "latest\b"` ]];
  then
    docker tag $BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH:latest $BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH:stable;
fi

docker build . -f Dockerfile.api -t $BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH:latest
docker push $BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH:latest

if [[ -n `docker images | grep "$BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH\b" | grep "stable\b"` ]];
  then
    docker push $BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH:stable;
fi
```

Could anyone please give me a hint what I could do in order to make this work or achieve the same result differently? I have a feeling it has to do something with quoting, but I don't understand shell much.

Comment: So debug the script. Add `set -x` and see what happens. I guess `BACKEND_DOCKER_IMAGE_PATH` variable is empty.

Comment: it is not empty because some lines of the script work correctly on CI too